# How to close browser tab/window using UiApp/Appscript?

Tags: google-apps-script

So, I have a doPost() handler using UiApp which displays an information message after a form's contents are stored.  How do I embed into the rendered doPost() page a close button which closes the tab/window without going back to the server.

I'm essentially trying to duplicate the following functionality which is HTML/Javascript but using Appscript/UiApp:

```
<input type="button" class="btn" value="Close window" onClick="self.close();">
```

Would be great to have a function like:

```
app.createClientCloseButton("Close window");
```

This function would embed the necessary HTML/Javascript in the rendered client page.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to give you the bad news, but this is not possible and from the explanation [on this issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=474), it is not going to be implemented either.